# How do I convert JSON data to display in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am trying to display JSON data that I retrieve from an ajax call but I am unable to display any data despite getting the JSON object just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://servername:10000/_vti_bin/webservice/service1.svc/getListTitle",
  {
    username: "a",
    password: "b",
    list: "calendar",
  },
  function(data) {
    alert(1);
    // and the rest
  }
)
});

</script>

<body>
</body
</html>
```

I don't get any alerts but using Fiddler I can see the JSON object.

```
{"GetListTitleResult":"Calendar"}
```

So what am I missing here? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems like the code doesn't go all the way to the function(data) part. But firebug doesn't show any syntax errors either. I still get the JSON response through Fiddler. Any help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code this way -

```
$.getJSON("http://servername:10000/_vti_bin/webservice/service1.svc/getListTitle",
{
    username: "a",
    password: "b",
    list: "calendar",
},
function(data)
{
    $.each(data, function(i,item)
    {
        alert(item);
    });
});
```

In my opinion, these are the following mistakes that you've made -

1. Since `data` itself will be a collection, you don't need to get `data.items`. Just pass the `data` as is to the `each` function.
2. The callback of the `each` iterator will be passed the `key` and the `value` for each item in the collection. Hence, `i` will be `GetListTitleResult`, and `item` will be `Calendar`.

Comment: no alerts popped up either. but as usual i can see the JSON response through Fiddler.

Comment: This is right on except that you do not specify `success:` for the callback. You just pass an anonymous function when using `$.getJSON`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Hong Yi: Do one thing. Inside `success`, try to print the `data`, like this - `alert(data)`. See if something pops up.

Comment: @Bryan Downing: Yes you are right. I'll edit my answer right away!

Comment: I still don't get any alerts or popups. And I have already removed `success` from the code already. Is there something that I'm missing? It seems like the code doesn't enter that step therefore nothing popups.

Comment: @Hong Yi: It seems so. Do one thing: specify `type` attribute in the `script` element like this - `type="text/javascript"`, then try to create a pop up before calling `getJSON` just to make sure if your JS code is working. If it's working, and still your code inside the callback doesn't execute, then there maybe a problem with the service that you are calling.

Comment: I doubt that there is something wrong with the service that I'm calling because I'm getting the JSON response through Fiddler but just not popping up inside the code. I still suspect that there is something wrong with the syntax but just can't figure out what. [http://www.mediafire.com/?ox7vuacdtm0hcgg] I have attached the html file here. Thanks for helping. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the method signature for `getJSON()`. You don't need to key the success callback with `success:`. You also have a few too many braces, brackets and semi-colons. Change it to

```
$.getJSON("http://servername:10000/_vti_bin/webservice/service1.svc/getListTitle",
  {
    username: "a",
    password: "b",
    list: "calendar",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // and the rest
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't get any data at all from the console. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

if you method looks like this:

```
public string getListTitle(string username, string password, string list, string format)
```

then your ajax data is good. If it's like this:

```
public string getListTitle(MyObject data)
```

then you need this:

```
{data: { 
    username: "a",
    password: "b",
    list: "calendar",
    format: "json"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
function(data) {
    alert(data.GetListTitleResult);
});
```

Comment: my ajax data is good. the json response i get back is correct. just that I cannot get it to display.